# Correlation and thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, correlation-functions, information

I have two systems that are correlated, their energy levels are not independent: $\rho(E_1,E_2) \ne \rho(E_1)\rho(E_2)$.

So I wanted to quantify the amount of dependence they have, I used the mutual information between the two partition functions $ I(Z_1, Z_2)$, also calculated $E_{tot}- E_1 -E_2$, $S_{tot}- S_1 -S_2$ that emphasize the fact that they are not independent, but I was wondering is there is a better way to quantify the amount of correlations, with thermodynamics variables?

Comment: Correlation function. What is missing in your question is: *correlation of what?* Mutual information is calculated between probability distributions (not partition functions.) If you have full probability distributions, you know everything about how the systems are correlated. The difficulty is likely in representing this information, which means extracting something essential, looking at a simpler quantity.

Comment: The energy levels of my two systems are correlated, okay, then I should calculate the mutual information between the density of states?

Comment: What you calculate depends on the nature of your system. What do you really want to demonstrate? That they are correlated? - you already know that. Even a simple correlation function, like $K_{12} = \langle E_1 E_2\rangle-\langle E_1\rangle\langle E_2\rangle$ might be meaningful.

Comment: I want to quantify the amount of correlation, in a thermodynamic way. I thought about the mutual information, but it's not a thermodynamic variable.

Comment: I have calculated $E_{tot} - E_1 - E_2$ and $S_{tot} - S_1 - S_2$, where $E_i$ and $S_i$ are the individual energy and entropy, and then I get a non-zero result that only comes from the correlations, but I was wondering if there is a better way to highlight and quantify these correlations

Answer (score 1):

Classical thermodynamics always assumes entropy is an extensive function. This is equivalent to saying mutual information is considered to be $0$ when systems are spatially separated because:

$$S(A,B)=S(A)+S(B)-I(A,B)$$

Strictly speaking, this is false when two systems interacted in the past, but this approximation works perfectly for ordinary macroscopic systems.

In statistical mechanics, we define entropy and mutual information for a distribution of the microstates, not macrostates. If it is impossible to measure the energies approximatively, and if we consider a distribution of possible energies as the macrostate, the energy is no longer a macro-variable. What is a macro-variable is the "average" energy (expected value of the energy for the distribution). It is the case for a non-macroscopic system in the canonical ensemble.

You have two ways of treating a correlation:

- define or compute a clear distribution for the microstate of the combined system $(A,B)$ and then compute entropies and mutual information for this distribution.
- treat the problem as a statistical problem on the macro-variables. Then you can use information theoretic entropy and mutual information of any of these variables. But this does not correspond to the physical entropy at all.

From what I guess from your question, you sound more in the second case.

Comment: I see, thank you. Maybe for clarifications, when I calculate the mutual information between my two partition functions, I am measuring the statistical correlation (in my statistical model) that are not the same as the physical ones? So then it doesn't make sense to try to have a thermodynamic interpretation of this mutual information

Comment: Yes. That is correct.